# PyGObject on Windows "ERROR:root:Could not find any typelib for Gtk"

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk3, pygobject

I need help setting up PyGObject under Windows. I've [installed it](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pygobjectwin32/files/) but I get the following error when importing `Gtk` and `Gdk` from `gi.repository`

```
ERROR:root:Could not find any typelib for Gtk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 2, in <module>
    from gi.repository import Gtk
ImportError: cannot import name Gtk
```

I'm able to import `gi.repository.GLib`, `gi.repository.Gio`, `gi.repository.GObject`, `gi.repository.cairo` and `cairo` but I can't import `gi.repository.Gtk` and `gi.repository.Gdk` and `gi.repository.GdkPixbuf`.

I have tried uninstalling it from the uninstaller in *add/remove programs* and then reinstalling it but the error persisted.

If someone could help that would be really appreciated.

Comment: What version of windows are you using?

Comment: @Sam Windows 7, 32 bits.

Comment: This is probably also related to why the Ubuntu Software Center is broken on my OS as well (Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit). I have the exact same error (just with an added import from the module that it doesn't get to process).

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this is the right answer but check if you have 
Gtk-version_number.typelib file in you installation. I had similar problem but I had this problem when I built my program with pyinstaller. I just copied .typelib files and my program worked. I dont know if this applies here but try finding that file and copying to installation sub directory where other .typelib files are.